# ciclo for javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

como seria la sintaxis de un ciclo for anidado, para recorrer una matris de 7x7 y anexar una serie de imagenes de manera aleatoria?

para la parte aleatoria cree una variabe de Math.random, que no se en que punto de la sintaxis usar.

tambien se que tengo que tener dos elementos o variables (i, j) que uno seria las columnas y otro seria las filas.

estoy empezando a estudiar programacion
seria un gusto que me pudieras explicar y el porque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido a SOe!

Las matrices suelen ser de dos dimensiones, como la que describes tu.
Recorrer una matriz es sencillo, los bucles for son así:

```js
for(let i=0; i < cantidadFilas; i++){ *
 for(let j=0; j < cantidadElementosXFila; j++){ **
  //aquí insertas tu imagen aleatoria
 }
}
```

*Donde la cantidad de filas es 7 en tu caso,este bucle saltará solo de fila en fila, sobre las 7 filas, sin entrar a cada uno de sus elementos

**Este bucle recorrerá por cada iteración del bucle de arriba, todos los elementos de la fila en las que se halle, en ese momento, por ejemplo cuando i=0, será la iteración sobre la primera fila, siendo que este segundo bucle recorrerá tus 7 elementos (cuando j =0, tu 1º elemento, cuando j=1, tu segundo elemento, y así sucesivamente).

**NOTA**: La notación de los asteriscos es únicamente usada para referir a la explicación de cada bucle y contribuir a la limpieza del código usado como ejemplo, no debes incluirla en tu código.

Tienes una bonita fuente de información para profundizar en un bucle for aquí: [MDN: Comunidad de desarrolladores de Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Bucles_e_iteraci%C3%B3n)

Siéntete libre de participar y preguntar en esta comunidad así como de contribuir en ella siempre que quieras, respetando las normas claro.

Comment: y que hace la propiedad let en esta caso?

Comment: No es una propiedad, es la declaración de la variable. En JavaScript las variables se solían declarar así `var i = 5`, a partir de ES5(estándar de JavaScript, sus normas vamos), las variables es preferible declararlas así : `let i = 5`.